# Generate random and unique indexes with a range for n number of combinations

Tags: python, numpy, random, random-seed

I'm want to make a random searcher of parameters but I don't know how to generate a random but unique combination of indexes, under a range. For example, I have these parameters:

```
    hyperparams  = {
        'size': [200, 300, 400],
        'min_count': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        'iter': [50, 100],
        'window': [4, 5, 7, 10],
        'alpha': [0.025, 0.01],
        'min_alpha': [0.025, 1e-4],
    }
```

I want to generate unique combinations of them, and each index has a range for n number of time.
Suppose it will generate 500 possible combinations. I want to take just 100 of them, randomly, but on these 100 anyone of them are repeated.
i.e.

```
random_and_unique_combination=[1,3,2,1,2,1]
```

which...

> Index 0 is the size.
>
> Index 1 is min_count.
>
> Index 2 is iter.
>
> and so on...

So later on I access the dictionary with

```
::
size = hyperparams['size'][1]
min_count = hyperparams['min_count'][3]
iter = hyperparams['iter'][2]
::
::
```

Comment: Dictionaries (except for in CPython) have no order...

Comment: Later on I will use these combinations to access the Dictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want a non-repeating sequence of tuples of numbers within a certain range.

**EDIT** *0*:

I believe your best bet is to first create all possible combinations, and then shuffle them:

```
import itertools
import random


def random_unique_combinations_k0(items, k):
    # generate all possible combinations
    combinations = list(itertools.product(*[item for item in items]))
    # shuffle them
    random.shuffle(combinations)
    for combination in itertools.islice(combinations, k):
        yield combination
```

**EDIT** *1*:

If generating all combination is too expensive in terms of memory, you may want to go by trial and error and refuse non-unique combinations.
One way of doing this is:

```
import itertools
import random
import functools


def prod(items):
    return functools.reduce(lambda x, y: x * y, items)


def random_unique_combinations_k1(items, k):
    max_lens = [len(list(item)) for item in items]
    max_num_combinations = prod(max_lens)

    # use `set` to ensure uniqueness
    index_combinations = set()
    # make sure that with the chosen number the next loop can exit
    # WARNING: if `k` is too close to the total number of combinations,
    # it may take a while until the next valid combination is found
    while len(index_combinations) < min(k, max_num_combinations):
        index_combinations.add(tuple(
            random.randint(0, max_len - 1) for max_len in max_lens))

    # make sure their order is shuffled
    # (`set` seems to sort its content)
    index_combinations = list(index_combinations)
    random.shuffle(index_combinations)
    for index_combination in itertools.islice(index_combinations, k):
        yield tuple(item[i] for i, item in zip(index_combination, items))
```

(This could also be implemented only with lists and checking for uniqueness before adding the `combination`, also rendering `random.shuffle()` superfluous, but from my tests these was slower than using `set`s.)

**EDIT** *2*:

Probably the least memory hungry method is to actually shuffle the generators and then use `itertools.product()` on them.

```
import random
import itertools


def pseudo_random_unique_combinations_k(items, k):
    # randomize generators
    comb_gens = list(items)
    for i, comb_gen in enumerate(comb_gens):
        random.shuffle(list(comb_gens[i]))
    # get the first `num` combinations
    combinations = list(itertools.islice(itertools.product(*comb_gens), k))
    random.shuffle(combinations)
    for combination in itertools.islice(combinations, k):
        yield tuple(combination)
```

which will obviously sacrifice some of the randomness.

**EDIT** *3*:

Following up on @Divakar approach, I wrote yet another version, which seems relatively efficient, but it is likely that it will be limited by the capabilities of `random.sample()`.

```
import random
import functools


def prod(items):
    return functools.reduce(lambda x, y: x * y, items)


def random_unique_combinations_k3(items, k):
    max_lens = [len(list(item)) for item in items]
    max_num_combinations = prod(max_lens)
    for i in random.sample(range(max_num_combinations), k):
        index_combination = []
        for max_len in max_lens:
            index_combination.append(i % max_len)
            i = i // max_len
        yield tuple(item[i] for i, item in zip(index_combination, items))
```

**TESTS**

On the requested input, they perform all reasonably fast, with the `0` method being the fastest (surprisingly even faster than the `2` or `pseudo` method), the `1` method the slowest, and, the `3` method as somewhere in between.
The `sklearn.model_selection.ParameterSampler` approach is of comparable speed as the the method `1`.

```
items = [v for k, v in hyperparams.items()]
num = 100

%timeit list(random_unique_combinations_k0(items, num))
615 µs ± 4.87 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit list(random_unique_combinations_k1(items, num))
2.51 ms ± 33.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit list(pseudo_random_unique_combinations_k(items, num))
179 µs ± 1.41 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

%timeit list(random_unique_combinations_k3(items, num))
570 µs ± 35.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

# the `sklearn` method which is slightly different in that it is
# also accessing the underling dictiornary    
import from sklearn.model_selection import ParameterSampler
%timeit list(ParameterSampler(hyperparams, n_iter=num))
2.86 ms ± 171 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

As a side note, I would then make sure that you `hyperparams` is a `collections.OrderedDict` because the `dict` is not guaranteed to be ordered across different versions of Python.

For slightly larger objects, we start seeing limits:

```
items = [range(50)] * 5
num = 1000

%timeit list(random_unique_combinations_k0(items, num))
# Memory Error

%timeit list(random_unique_combinations_k1(items, num))
19.3 ms ± 273 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit list(pseudo_random_unique_combinations_k(items, num))
1.82 ms ± 14.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit list(random_unique_combinations_k3(items, num))
2.31 ms ± 28.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Even more so for larger objects:

```
items = [range(50)] * 50
num = 1000

%timeit list(random_unique_combinations_k0(items, num))
# Memory Error

%timeit list(random_unique_combinations_k1(items, num))
149 ms ± 3.45 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit list(pseudo_random_unique_combinations_k(items, num))
4.92 ms ± 20.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit list(random_unique_combinations_k3(items, num))
# OverflowError
```

**SUMMARY**:

Method `0` is likely not to fit in memory, method `1` is the slowest but it is likely to be the more robust, method `3` gives the best performances if it does not run into overflow problems, while method `2` (`pseudo`) is the fastest and less memory-hungry method, but it will produce somewhat "less random" combinations.

Comment: As soon as I test it I will consider as correct, but seems that these last 2 ideas can solve the case. I think that I need tk have more creativity when thinking on thsese problems. You solved it with a good creativity. Thanks :)

Comment: So, I ran both the Edit approaches and I was expecting three columns in the output to have 0s and 1s only corresponding to the three keys that have two elements, but I am not seeing that. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Ah I think you are covering 0 to n, i.e. including n, with n as the lengths of values for each key, That could explain it.

Comment: Exactly... since they need to be index, a wise -1 somewhere should be added somewhere.

Comment: Now the index problem was fixed (was only showing up in the second solution, because the numbers generated by `random.randint()` include both the extrema.

Comment: Can you modify your edit2, so that the result is stored somewhere? Would love to time it.

Comment: Done. Let us know :-)

Comment: Ah but that doesn't look random :)

Comment: Well, that's the price of being fast. Maybe it would *look* more random with a final `random.shuffle(combinations)` ?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hashing based approach to generate unique combinations and doesn't generate all combinations, just the number of combinations required -

```
num_comb = 100 # number of combinations needed

# We need ordered keys to maintain the indexing needed :
# Index 0 is the size, Index 1 is min_count, Index 2 is iter...
ordered_keys = ['size', 'min_count', 'iter', 'window', 'alpha','min_alpha']
lens = np.array([len(hyperparams[i]) for i in ordered_keys])

prod_lens = lens.cumprod()
idx = np.random.choice(prod_lens[-1], num_comb, replace=0)

N = len(lens)
out = np.zeros((num_comb,N),dtype=int)
r = idx
for i in range(2,N+1):
    d = r//prod_lens[-i]
    r = r - d*prod_lens[-i]
    out[:,-i+1] = d
out[:,0] = r
```

**Runtime test**

Timing three approaches posted thus far to solve the problem that don't generate all combinations and that are truly random - @norok2-Edit1, @scnerd and one posted in this post for three sets of output lengths -

```
In [442]: hyperparams  = {
     ...:         'size': [200, 300, 400],
     ...:         'min_count': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
     ...:         'iter': [50, 100],
     ...:         'window': [4, 5, 7, 10],
     ...:         'alpha': [0.025, 0.01],
     ...:         'min_alpha': [0.025, 1e-4],
     ...:     }

In [443]: %timeit norok2_edit1(hyperparams, num=100)
     ...: %timeit scnerd(hyperparams, num=100)
     ...: %timeit divakar(hyperparams, num_comb=100)
     ...: 
1000 loops, best of 3: 612 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.03 ms per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 57.9 µs per loop

In [444]: %timeit norok2_edit1(hyperparams, num=200)
     ...: %timeit scnerd(hyperparams, num=200)
     ...: %timeit divakar(hyperparams, num_comb=200)
     ...: 
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.39 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 2 ms per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 66.5 µs per loop

In [445]: %timeit norok2_edit1(hyperparams, num=400)
     ...: %timeit scnerd(hyperparams, num=400)
     ...: %timeit divakar(hyperparams, num_comb=400)
     ...: 
100 loops, best of 3: 4.5 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 4.01 ms per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 77.5 µs per loop
```

Comment: I was thinking on incrementalling the seed. What about?

Comment: @denisCandido This generates one random combination within the constraints of ranges. Are you looking to generate all combinations?

Comment: My guess is that perhaps @denisCandido actually means to index from zero?

Comment: No, all combinations I could just use a iteration. Suppose it will generate 500 combinations. I want to take just 100 of them, randomly but on these 100 anyone of them are repeated.

Comment: @denisCandido If you are using this in a loop, it won't be unique. Guess I wasn't clear on that.

Comment: Yes, it you not, but I don't want all combinations due the large amount of time it will require to process. I just want n unique combinations.

Comment: @denisCandido Good to see you updated question with those details. To me, those  were not clear the first time around :)

Comment: @denisCandido Be sure to check out the newly edited approach too.

Comment: @Divakar interesting approach, but I would use Python integers and a generator instead of creating everything at the beginning and I'd avoid using NumPy because of the limited integer precision.

Answer (score 0):

`scikit-learn` needs to solve exactly this problem to implement [RandomizedSearchCV](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.RandomizedSearchCV.html#sklearn.model_selection.RandomizedSearchCV), and they have a separate class [ParameterSampler](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.ParameterSampler.html) that does this which you could use:

```
In [1]: from sklearn.model_selection import ParameterSampler

In [2]: list(ParameterSampler({'a': [1,2,3], 'b': ['x', 'y', 'z'], 'c': [0.1, 0.2, 0.3]}, n_iter=5))
Out[2]:
[{'a': 3, 'b': 'z', 'c': 0.2},
 {'a': 3, 'b': 'y', 'c': 0.1},
 {'a': 3, 'b': 'z', 'c': 0.1},
 {'a': 3, 'b': 'x', 'c': 0.2},
 {'a': 1, 'b': 'y', 'c': 0.3}]
```

It's not the indices, but you could easily solve that little problem by replacing your value lists with index lists:

```
In [1]: from sklearn.model_selection import ParameterSampler

In [2]: params = {'a': [1,2,3], 'b': ['x', 'y', 'z'], 'c': [0.1, 0.2, 0.3]}

In [3]: param_idxs = {key: list(range(len(vals))) for key, vals in params.items()}

In [4]: list(ParameterSampler(param_idxs, n_iter=5))
Out[4]:
[{'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 0},
 {'a': 1, 'b': 0, 'c': 2},
 {'a': 0, 'b': 2, 'c': 1},
 {'a': 1, 'b': 0, 'c': 1},
 {'a': 2, 'b': 0, 'c': 0}]
```

And [according to the documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.ParameterSampler.html#sklearn-model-selection-parametersampler), you won't get any repeats:

> If all parameters are presented as a list, sampling without
>   replacement is performed.

A quick skim through the [current source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/ef5cb84a/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py#L167) says that, when all your parameters are given as lists, it generates all possible options and performs a random sampling from that. That won't be an issue in most cases, but if you have a huge number of hyperparameter options, it could suck up a fair amount of memory.

Comment: Do you think this will be faster than all the method indicated earlier?

Comment: Faster to implement, easier to maintain, yes. Faster in runtime? I haven't delved into the precise implementation used by scikit-learn, but it's probably competitive with the other solutions here. If you're really concerned about performance, implement all the above solutions and benchmark them

Comment: Except for really high dimensionality, runtime won't be significant for any solution

Comment: I double checked and this is actually faster in runtime. Nevertheless, I would not added Yet Another Dependency™ to software if the library is not stable yet and the alternative is relatively simple.